# Reading in and merging numeric intervals into ranges?

Tags: r, file-io, intervals, cut

I have a dataset of the time stamped records.

I perform some analysis using the function 'aggregate' over the time.

The output file have a column that looks like:

```
"Group.1"   "V1"    "V2"
"1" "(1.46758021e+09,1.46758027e+09]"   XXX YYY
"2" "(1.46758027e+09,1.46758033e+09]"   XXXXX   YYYY
"3" "(1.46758033e+09,1.46758039e+09]"   XXXXXXX YYYYY
....
```

What's the type of the column "Group.1" ? (It looks like a range of something)

I need to merge several ranges and get the subset of "V1" and "V2" according corresponding to the range.

//

Original data

```
"Epoch"    "Value"
  1           10
  7           12
  11          15
  ...
```

What I did:

```
bean_size = 60; 1min
start_epoch = XX
end_epoch = YY
time_range = seq(start_epoch, end_epoch, bean_size)
agg <- aggregate(data_table$value, list(cut(data_table$epoch, breaks = time_range)), sum)
```

I want to store the data 'agg' with a format like:

```
"Epoch"    "Agg_Value"
   1            X
  61            Y
 121            Z
....
```

"Epoch" is the begin time epoch of each range of aggregation.

Comment: Could be seconds since a certain epoch started. `strptime(1.46758021e+09,format="%s")` yields `2016-07-03 16:10:10 CDT`

Comment: @ddunn801 yes exactly, but I'd like to deal with the each epoch not the range.

Comment: The item in the column that looks like "(1.46758021e+09,1.46758027e+09]" is most probably factor-type resulting from a `cut()` operation. They are typically open on the left (open left parenthesis) and closed on the right (square-right-bracket). You should post the data before whatever aggregate operation you did and describe what you wnat to do. Trying to (re)work with time data after it's been turned into a factor is going to be a complete PITA.

Comment: @42- exactly!, is there any way not to make the time range for aggregation into a factor? I am parsing the factor as a string whenever I read the data again.

Comment: There are packages that define interval types, but factor levels returned by `cut` are by definition going to be 'character'. As I _arlready_ said.... post the original data and specify what you want to occur. Then we can discuss whether to keep the endpoints in atwo columns or use some other mechanism.

Comment: @42- I updated,

Comment: Looks like you read in a CSV file where everything was quoted (so that they could export the cut factor intervals)?

Comment: Also you want to set `options('scipen'=+20)` to avoid the unwanted scientific notation on your epoch values.